# Debugging emacs consuming 100%, but still responsive

Tags: emacs, strace

I notice that emacs is consuming 100% of cpu. An strace of the emacs process shows that it is writting the following text:

```
Wrong type argument: window-live-p, #<window 3>
Wrong type argument: window-live-p, #<window 3>
Wrong type argument: window-live-p, #<window 3>
Wrong type argument: window-live-p, #<window 3>
Wrong type argument: window-live-p, #<window 3>
```

and so on.

The text is being written to a file descriptor which according to /proc/.../fd/ is a pipe.

Emacs is still responsive, so this must be code that is running on the "background".

How can identify which code is responsible for this and debug it?

Edit:
I checked the pipe number to which this text is being written, and did an lsof. I see that the text is possibly interacting with dconf, and gdbus.

```
$lsof |grep 6967
sh         7147          myuser    1w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
sh         7147          myuser    2w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
emacs      7148          myuser    1w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
emacs      7148          myuser    2w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
dconf      7148  7149    myuser    1w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
dconf      7148  7149    myuser    2w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
gdbus      7148  7151    myuser    1w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
gdbus      7148  7151    myuser    2w     FIFO                0,8      0t0    6967 pipe
$
```

To be honest, the actual strace output is the following:

```
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "W", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "r", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "o", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "n", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "g", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, " ", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "t", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "y", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "p", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "e", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, " ", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "a", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "r", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "g", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "u", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "m", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "e", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "n", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "t", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, ":", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, " ", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "w", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "i", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "n", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "d", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "o", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "w", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "-", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "l", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "i", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "v", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "e", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "-", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "p", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, ",", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, " ", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "#", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "<", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "w", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "i", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "n", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "d", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "o", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "w", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, " ", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "3", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, ">", 1)                        = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
write(2, "\n", 1)                       = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
```

So it is writing what I originally wrote, but one character at a time. However, it seems to be writing this to a broken pipe.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out portions of your `.emacs` or `init.el` user configuration files to track down the code that is responsible?  Have you tried running Emacs with no user configuration file -- i.e., a blank `.emacs` or a blank `init.el` file?

Comment: this isn't a problem that happens all the time or that is even frequent, also, my .emacs is too large for that kind of approach. also, I'm more interested in figuring out how to debug these issues in general. I'm sure that this is code that is running in the "background", maybe with 'sit-for', but I'd like to know how to identify it. I'm currently looking into timer-list, but I asked hoping that someone would answer who is more familiar with this.

Comment: Please don't make the mistake of assuming that I do not know what I'm talking about.  Have you tried `(setq debug-on-error t)` to enable broader debugging information?

Comment: What exactly makes you think I did? I'm just more interested in learning how to debug these issues in a targeted way, and I'm not interested in a trial-and error approach. I know this code is running somewhere in my emacs session, and I'd like to know what it is. I do have debug-on-error set, but this doesn't show a backtrace.

Comment: My apologies, then, I misinterpreted the portion of your comment that stated *" . . ., but I asked hoping that someone would answer who is more familiar with this"*.  I stand corrected.  I'll let other forum participants take over from here.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant is that, rather that trying to figure this out on my own by looking at the sources of functions I know nothing about and which I only suspect based on their names that they might help me debug an issue like this, to have someone, not excluding you, who already is familiar enough with how emacs works to help me trace down the issue.

Comment: FWIW, the blind approach of a binary search on the code you load is actually a very **good** way to narrow things down. And it is **quick**, in spite of what one might think a priori. This is likely behind @lawlist's suggestions. Recursively comment out 1/2, 3/4, 7/8, 15/16... of your init file to discover which code you are invoking is problematic. But first, as @lawlist also suggested, try starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file) to see whether the problem is in fact introduced by your init file.

Comment: I use that approach all the time, particularly when my .emacs won't load till the end. The main issue with that approach here is that I can't reproduce the behavior, so there's no way for me to quickly verify whether a change was successful. Surely there must be other approaches, especially when strace is telling me exactly what is the continuous error. There must be something constantly looping and writing to a file/pipe. I suspect that there is a more efficient way of identifying the culprit here.

Comment: Apparently this issue had to do with another emacs session I had started (and closed) on tty3. Since I had closed, I became confused thinking that the problem was with the session I was using. This explains why the latter was still responsive. I still have no idea what caused the issue on the other session, especially since the process hung long after I had exited emacs on the tty.

Comment: @erjoalgo have you identified the problem more precisely ? I'm seeing the same issue here, same `gdbus` and `dconf` lsof result, but I don,t have any other emacs sessions nor did I try to open some.